# How To Get The Total Time In Hrs

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, aggregate-functions

I have A table named tblMaintainsHdr
In that i have The Following Columns

```
asset_ID maintns_StrtDate Maintns_EndDate  Maintains_strtTime      Maintains_EndTime

 1       2011-12-09       2011-12-09     2011-12-09 12:03:00.000   2011-12-09 12:03:00.000
 2       2011-12-10       2011-12-12     2011-12-10 12:03:00.000   2011-12-12 12:03:00.000
```

I need to calculate The Total Maintainenance Hrs considering the columns

`maintains start time`, `maintains end time`, `maintains start date`, `maintains end date`

Comment: Hello @Lijina , Need to add Maintainenance start date or end date.. If we consider only startTime and End Time then ? If we added both into time then total hours became 96 otherwise 48 hours right!!

Comment: Consider only The maintenace start time and maintenace end time..as it is a datetime field

Comment: Consider my below reply..Use this section : /*  Without adding maintanance Start Date and End Date   */

Answer (score 0):

Use below SQL script.

```
    Declare @TableVar table(startDt Datetime, endDt Datetime, startTm dateTime, endTm dateTime)

    select * from @TableVar
    insert into @TableVar values ('2011-12-09','2011-12-09','2011-12-09 12:03:00.000','2011-12-09 12:03:00.000')
    insert into  @TableVar values('2011-12-10','2011-12-12','2011-12-10 12:03:00.000','2011-12-12 12:03:00.000')

/*  Without adding maintanance Start Date and End Date   */
 select 
        tot=sum(
                DATEDIFF(hh ,startTm ,endTm )
        )
    from @TableVar
-- It returns 48


/* With adding maintanance Start Date and End Date   */
    select 
        tot=sum(
                DATEDIFF(hh ,startDt + startTm ,endDt+endTm)
        )
    from @TableVar
-- It returns 96
```

Let me know if not worked..
If my answer worked tick Mark as Answer